# Strange pagination 404 issue with custom post type

Tags: pagination, http-status-code-404, archive, custom-post-type

I have a really strange problem trying to paginate custom posts types in their archives page, I created a custom post type called `property` and set an archive page called `properties` to show them all.

So inside my `archive-property.php` file added a form (`GET` method) with a dropdown box so users are able to set how many posts they want to display per page, it looks like this:

```
<select name="prop_number" id="prop_number">
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

So before everything I do:

```
if (isset($_GET)) {

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $query_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'property',
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 12 // Default number of properties per page
    );

    // Custom number properties per page
    if (isset($_GET['prop_number']) && !empty($_GET['prop_number'])) {
        $query_args['posts_per_page'] = $_GET['prop_number'];
    }
}

query_posts($query_args); 

// Do loop and other stuff
```

It works fine but when I use `next_posts_link()` to get to the second page I get a page not found 404 error, however if I go to my WP admin area and set the "Blog pages show at most" option to the same number I want per page in my select box (for example I manually set 25 on "Blog pages show at most" and select 25 in my `prop_number` select box) it does work fine.

I even tried using the [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin and it does render the correct amount of numbers depending on how many properties I want to show but I have the same problem 404 pages on any page I try to go unless I manually set the page in the backend.

If I didn't need the option to choose how many properties I want to show I'd just set the number manually but since users can choose between 3 options I can't set this to a fixed number in the backend.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you ever resolved your issue, but for the sake of anyone finding this question you may want to try flushing your permalink structure.

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules:

```
//Ensure the $wp_rewrite global is loaded
global $wp_rewrite;
//Call flush_rules() as a method of the $wp_rewrite object
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Put that in your functions.php file, refresh your page, and see if that fixes your problem. It has for me in the past when I've had pagination 404 issues.

**NOTE: once you have flushed your permalinks, remember to erase those two lines (see above) as you do not need or want that running every time a page is requested** - it only needs to be done once. (This entire action may or may not be the same as going to the Permalinks page in your admin console.)